# What kind of edging should I use between a patio and a French drain?

Tags: patio

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to achieve
My patio is pretty much flat. Due to settling the water collects near the wall
Since it is too much work to grade properly the entire patio I think that it would be good to rest the areas where the water collects and to add a french drain between the patio and the wall. The wall is presenting efflorescence due to too much water at the base. The water goes up on the wall due to capillarity pressure.

So ..what sort of can be used between the french drain and the patio (see the picture, the edge pointed by the arrow)

[image]

**Edit:**

### Someone on another site suggested something like this

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an answer like "gravel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea that might work for you...
[image]

Here is a revised drawing added to the first one, with the idea you had given to you and I added where the various barriers need to be.
[image]

I forgot to note in the drawing that the gray line is the filter cloth.

The full wrap of the plastic membrane will keep the excess water from migrating back to the house. Just placing it against the wall and the bottom will allow it to get to the walls still. Remember it will be a LOT of water concentrated there.

The plastic liner will act as an in ground gutter to move the water, so be sure the bottom is accurately graded towards a place the water can flow that will do the house no harm.

Comment: It may be better to place the heavy plastic between the 2x and the side with the sand and brick, locking it in with the paver edge

Comment: Thanks Jack!
Someone on another site suggested the solution illustrated in the image posted above in my initial message..What do you think about that?
Your solution is interesting too but I am not comfortable with the idea of having the wood in there not even treated wood

Comment: The wood blocks between the wall and 2x could be temporary, they are only there to hold the border parts inline until the gravel for the drain is in place. You will need filter cloth between the sand bed and the gravel of the french drain, otherwise it will wash down into the french drain. Otherwise, that is a great idea. I wish I had thought of it myself.... Are you aware you can post and approve your own answer here?

Comment: Hi Jack 
Yes I am but I don't know if it is a good idea to do that since:
-I am not the one who found the solution
-others of this discussion board might come with another solution. 
I also think that this is discouraged by the forum admins, some would just love to get points although I don;t see their point :-)

Comment: my drawing is not very clear, but actually the patio and the french drain will share the same gravel in that area where they intersect. I should have used the same colour. However you have a good point, in that area the sand might migrate downward through the gravel. 
On the same note, I can't understand why that doesn't happen where there is only patio, sand and gravel (no french drain) Whater is still coming from above..and it will end up mixing the two layers ...does that really happen ?

Comment: Some folks, I believe, do that to get points. You already stated you got the idea from another site. Nobody here supplied you with a better idea yet, and you found the answer yourself.

Comment: OK I have just done that. You are right, It is better this way, I already have some other questions that have no answer for the same reason or for the only reason that some ideas were provided in the comments section and not as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18183/discussion-between-jack-and-user2059078).

Comment: Question, is your "compactible gravel" washed gravel, or "bank run" as I call it. At least that is what I learned it as here in Maryland when the gravel is mined straight from the ground. Might you be using crushed stone?

Comment: I don't know yet what is under the patio, I have not opened it up yet.
The weather is so and so here and from what I understood I will have to use polymeric sand (see my older questions in this forum) to match the existing filler used before. That does not install well when the weather is wet. This is a larger project, a starting to age and settled pation which was neglected long time. It looks good but it is falling apart

Comment: I tried to get to get a chat room, but there was no chat box present in the room

Comment: I noticed that too. Anyway it is almost midnight here in Toronto, I will have to go to sleep. If you are curious watch these threads or my posts, I am going to post a 3D diagram with the house, patio and the french drain as I see it installed.

Comment: I just added a 3d representation of the space that I am working in, if that helps https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51874/french-drain-between-wall-and-patio-what-is-the-best-position-for-it